# Add autocomplete for the new added element

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have finished autocomplete using JQuery autocomplete. my requirements as follows:

Add autocomplete automatically for new added elements, these elements have a common class: speClass

1.I would like to read the value of the input box, I do not know how to read?

2.how to add autocomplete for new added element . it works only for the first input (displayed by default)

**headers:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<tbody id="items">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="speClass" name="specifications"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS**

```
function addItem() {
   var item = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='speClass'  name='specifications' /> </tr>" ;
   $("#items").append(item);
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var cache_com = {};
    $(".specClass").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var term = $(".speClass").val();
        if(term in cache_com) {
            alert(term);
            response($.map(cache_com[term], function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item,
                    value: item
                }

            }));
            return ;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "loadSpecList.action",
            data:{
                specQuery: term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                alert(term);
                cache_com[term] = data;
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                     return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                     }
                }));
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {

    }
    });
});
```

PS: I corrected variable error in the code

Answer (score 0):

replace

`$(".specifications").autocomplete({`

by

```
$(".specClass").autocomplete({
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a widget, you nee to call the widget initialization for each of the new elements

```
function addItem() {
    var item = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='speClass'  name='specifications' /> </tr>" ;
    var speClass =  $(item).appendTo($("#items")).find('.speClass');
    createAutocomplete(speClass)
}

var cache_com = {};
function createAutocomplete(els){
    els.autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if(term in cache_com) {
                alert(term);
                response($.map(cache_com[term], function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }

                }));
                return ;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "loadSpecList.action",
                data:{
                    specQuery: term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    alert(term);
                    cache_com[term] = data;
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {

        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    createAutocomplete($(".specifications"))
});
```

You can read the entered text using `request.term` in the source method

Comment: I can't mark your answer useful, because I don't have 15 reputation. This is my first post.